# Don't get your head in a spin!

Tags: code-golf, string, array

## Guidelines

#### Task

Write a function that takes in a sentence (a string, or list of characters) and reverses all the words that are greater than or equal to 5 in length.

---

#### Examples

`"Hey fellow code golfers" -> "Hey wollef code sreflog"`

`"I aM noT a cAr" -> "I aM noT a cAr"`

`"I Am a tRaiN" -> "I Am a NiaRt"`

---

#### Rules

- Since this is code golf, the person with the least amount of bytes as their answer wins.
- The input will have only one space between two adjacent words and there will be no trailing or leading spaces.
- The output must also only have one space between two adjacent words and no trailing or leading spaces.
- You can assume that the input will either be a string, or an array of characters. It WILL NOT be an array of words.
- You must output either a string, or an array of characters. You MUST NOT output an array of words.
- Words with punctuation marks can be seen as 5 or 4 letters, whichever you want
- Capitalisation should stay the same for the same letters

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73417/discussion-on-question-by-amorris-dont-get-your-head-in-a-spin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12 10 8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [dylnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75553/dylnan) (use of repeat, `¡`, as a replacement of if, `?`, saving the need for identity, `¹`.)

```
ḲṚṫ¡€5K
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pd856uHP1oYWPmtaYev///1/JPy9VoaQ8X6Ekoyg1VSEtv7RIIS2zLFXBUyElXyEnH8gqycgsViguyMzLy8xLV8gCSioBAA)**

#### How?

```
ḲṚṫ¡€5K - Link: list of characters
Ḳ       - split at spaces (gets words)
     5  - literal five
    €   - for €ach word:
   ¡    -   repeat:
  ṫ     -   ...number of times: tail (5th character on, if empty falsey->0, else truthy->1)
 Ṛ      -   ...action: reverse
      K - join with spaces
```

---

Previous 8: `ḲṚ¹ṫ?€5K`

Previous 10: `ḲµṚ¹ṫ?5µ€K`

Previous 12s: `ḲµUµL€>4Tµ¦K` and `ḲµṚ¹L>¥?4µ€K`

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pd856uHP1oYWPmtaYev///1/JI7VSIQ0onV@ukJyfkqqQnp@TllpUrJCYlJySqgQA). Also nice trick with `ṫ` and putting `€5` on the right side of `?` I didn't realize you could do that

Comment: Oh and I never knew that would work; thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
V`\w{5,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PywhprzaVKf2/3@P1EqFtNScnPxyheT8lFSF9PyctNSiYgA)

```
  \w{5,}     match 5 or more characters long strings
V`           reverse each match and insert in place
```

Comment: And we had such a nice chain going :(

Comment: Nice! I think it will be tricky to beat this.

Comment: Yep, this is close to optimal for any language. But why do you need the `\b`?

Comment: @ETHproductions I don't, thanks. Residue from the `*` mistake

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 123 bytes

```
,[[>++++[-<-------->]<[[-<+>]++++[-<++++++++>]>,>]<]<[>]<<<<<[[>]<[.<]>[>]]>>>>[[<]>[.>]]>>>>>,[>++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLCgIxEESvkn0@Jwi19g5FL3RMBjEYGBHx9LECmbdoqnh03Y7r41U/23OMQMILxhwXsExVD1vCL2AIktK6E87AlA0KBkHOklZDOMdxbkgnRtO/jXEpP1dLa/3rtn4vbu@tluP9Bw)

Most of this is just creating the ASCII value for space (32) 3 times, which is 51 bytes, or 41.4% of the total bytecount.

An attempt to only create one cell with 32 at the beginning and use that (124 bytes):

```
++++[->++++++++<],[[>[-<-<+>>>+<]<[[-<+>]>,>>>>]<[[-]>>>>]<<<]>>[-<+>]<<<<<<<<[[>]<[.<]>[[-]>]<<]>>>>[[<]>[.[-]>]]>,[>.>]<<]
```

Comment: Earned an upvote for doing it in BF.

Comment: Having posted my first brainfuck answer a couple of weeks ago, I have great respect for this. I'm sure I can learn a lot by these examples. Great effort.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

*-57 bytes, w/ help from @Amorris, @Oliver, @Shaggy*

```
s=>s.split` `.map(w=>w[4]?[...w].reverse().join``:w).join` `
```

My first ever codegolf submission!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! One thing I can see right off the bat to remove 2 bytes is the brackets around s, when you are passing the input to the f arrow function. That is not needed unless you have two variables to input.

Comment: You can replace `w.split('')` with `[...w]` and `.join(' ')` & `.join('')` can be replaced with backticks `.join\` \`` `.join\`\``

Comment: Why are you using `a` when you're already mapping over `s`? Also, the `()` around the length check are unecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, I've just made some changes. Thanks for the warm welcome too!

Comment: `w[4]`, not `w[5]` ;)

Comment: Oops! Darn indexing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)
-2 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)
-2 bytes thanks to [ElPedro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56555/elpedro)

```python
for w in input().split():print w[::len(w)<5or-1],
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFcITMPiApKSzQ09YoLcjKBtFVBUWZeiUJ5tJVVTmqeRrmmjWl@ka5hrM7//0oeqZUKaak5OfnlCsn5KakK6fk5aalFxUoA)

Comment: Save three moving to [Python 3 and a full program](https://tio.run/##HY3LCsMgFET3@YqLm2hoC32shHTdD@guZGGTayMYlXiLzddbLRwYGM4wYafFu2ue/Ix927Y5bMYR74Y0SHk@Xjpu0fEk7jcxar9BAuMK4UNcnGKwpuQoclk2/7a3an3NSlJTbao2e@AOGq31CeoNvL3VuEV2APZcTISCAsJITDYA@MWJV0/kHw)

Comment: You can use `[::len(w)<5or-1]` for -2 bytes.

Comment: [49](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFcITMPiApKSzQ09YoLcjKBtFVBUWZeiUJ5tJVVTmqeRrmmjWl@ka5hrM7//0oeqZUKaak5OfnlCsn5KakK6fk5aalFxUoA "49") by going back to Python 2 and using a standard for loop

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder - as hard as I try I can't figure out why `len(w)<5or-1` works. Any chance you can explain?

Comment: @ElPedro In Python, bools are subclasses of integers. Namely, `len(w)<5` returns either `True` - which is equivalent to `1` - or `False` - which is equivalent to `0`. In case this condition is true (the length is less than 5), `len(w)<5or-1` evaluates to `1`, so `w[::len(w)<5or-1]` gives `w[::1]`, which returns the string unchanged. In case the condition is false, then `len(w)<5or-1` is equivalent to `0 or -1`, which yields `-1` because `0` is falsy, and therefore `w[::len(w)<5or-1]` is the same as `w[::-1]`, which takes every element from the end of the string (i.e. it reverses it).

Comment: Many thanks @MrXcoder. That helps a lot. I used a kinda similar idea for my answer. It was the or that I couldn't follow. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 10 bytes

```apl
\w{5,}
⌽⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z@mvNpUp5brUc/eR71bff//90itVEhLzcnJL1dIzk9JVUjPz0lLLSoGAA)

```
\w{5,}   match 5 or more characters long strings
         and replace
 ⍵M      each match
⌽        with its reverse
```

Comment: Got an upvote for using a language I hadn't even heard of before!

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
f s|s>take 4s=reverse s|1<2=s
unwords.map f.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEAXvfsWjeLWgeDSe/QgvS7obS9MkZKtF6Ld3Dd6GgZkX6cQxWnBPe6c110H7mQqk//NBoJveF5oYV3WVP1yVmzvfLk5tpjHBodQxLTgioHvwF9KGeYXPAyPkKC3pYLuXSEHt5Ev5AQ)

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @totallyhuman.

Comment: [49 bytes.](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEAXvfsWjeLWgeDSe/QgvS7obS9MkZKtF6Ld3Dd6GgZkX6cQxWnBPe6c110H7mQqk//NBoJveF5oYV3WVP1yVmzvfLk5tpjHBodQxLTgioHvwF9KGeYXPAyPkKC3pYLuXSEHt5Ev5AQ "Haskell – Try It Online") (`words that are greater than or equal to 5 in length`)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
ð¡εDg4›iR]ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/8wNWFiMWX//8OwwqHOtURnNOKAumlSXcOww73//0hleSBmZWxsb3cgY29kZSBnb2xmZXJz)

**Explanation**

```
ð¡             # split on spaces
  ε      ]     # apply to each word
   D           # duplicate
    g          # length
     4›        # greater than 4
       iR      # if true, reverse
          ðý  # join by space
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```
®Ê<5?Z:Zw}S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9C6w102pvZRVlHltcH//yt5pFYqpKXm5OSXKyTnp6QqpOfnpKUWFSsBAA)

#### Explanation

```
®        }S    Split on spaces and map each word Z through this function:
 Ê<5             If the length of Z is less than 5,
    ?Z             return Z unchanged.
      :Zw        Otherwise, return Z reversed.
               The words are then re-joined on spaces and sent to output.
```

---

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2, 11 bytes

```
r/\w{5,}/_w
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9cd3s1LH0vX3c=&input=IkhleSBmZWxsb3cgY29kZSBnb2xmZXJzIg==)

Thought of this just before the Retina answer was posted. Replaces each match of `/\w{5,}/g` with the match reversed.

Comment: Fun fact: this would be 7 bytes according to the current [feature plan for v2](https://hackmd.io/MwQwrAHMwEYwtBAZgTgCzzTAjGRATANhHiQAYBjJAdhgCZI7hCg=): `r»ẉ⁵⁻_w`

Comment: If only there were a shortcut for `l `, your second solution could be 11 bytes too! ;)

Comment: @Shaggy ...I'm a moron sometimes :P

Answer (score 1):

## C,  <s>105</s>  104 bytes

*Thanks to @ceilingcat for saving a byte!*

```c
i,k;f(char*s){for(i=0;s[k=i]>32;)++i;for(;i>4&&k--;)putchar(s[k]);~k&&write(1,s,i+=k=!!s[i]);k&&f(s+i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09C8IwFEX3/opnh5LYFvzaHi1000EHcZMOISb6SG0kqRQp@tdrOrh5p8c953FlfpVyHCkzqJm8CTf3fNDWMSoW6M@moLpcr5CnKeFUI5WbJDF5jvzx7KYHFqya48ckSe@oU2yZ@YzSwhSzmT9TQIFo5lPi@B6p7eAuqGU8GiII0Szeqhdo1TS2B2kvCq620cr5mGOY8CwOx0/dgdhDa08gQFbuv1HdA@2Ogg5T/R6/)

**Unrolled:**

```c
i, k;
f(char*s)
{
    for (i=0; s[k=i]>32;)
        ++i;

    for (; i>4&&k--;)
        putchar(s[k]);

    ~k && write(1, s, i+=k=!!s[i]);
    k && f(s+i);
}
```

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY2xCsIwFEX3fsUzQ3nRdhDcQoVuOuggbuIQYlIfqY3kRUREf73Gwc07Xe45cE3dGTOOVHnl0Jx1nLJ8uhDRN9RwioavA3IlQEhFy0VZ@rpW8npLXxf54I9SvX1Z3iMli/OKK5o1vplM@EAZZeKQZyTVa6QhwUXTgLJ4FpDjUKzsA5zt@3AHE04WutA7Gzmf5QtGkctPXYPewBD2oMG08b/RXjJNO03b7/waPw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 22 bytes

Includes `+1` for `p`

```
perl -pe 's/\w{5,}/reverse$&/eg' <<< "Hey fellow code golfers"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>63</s> <s>53</s> 43 bytes

```
i>::48*=$0(+?v
6ov!?lr?(5l~ <.1
*^>i:0(?;48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9POysrEQstWxUBD276Myyy/TNE@p8hewzSnTsFGz5BLK84u08pAw97axOL/f4/USoW01Jyc/HKF5PyUVIX0/Jy01KJiPQVPhURfhbz8EIVEhWTHIh0g3zEXyC4JSsz0AwA)

<sub><s>10</s> 20 bytes saved thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)!</sub>

Comment: Woah, yeah, guess I was more tired than I realized while making this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>74</s> 69 Bytes

```
def f(a):print' '.join([i if len(i)<5else i[::-1]for i in a.split()])
```

Edit: -5 thanks to @ElPedro

Comment: [69 (TIO)](https://tio.run/##DckxCsMwDADAr4gskYYGGuhi@oD@IWQIjdSqCMnYhpDXu7n18tm@4XPvOwsIbpRyUW8jjNMv1HFRUAFjR6Xng60y6JLS7b5KFLjSYZtqNm1IK3XB4cUnCJvFAe/YGT5hwqUO1P8 "Python 2 – Try It Online") - print instead of return, Python splits on space by default (don't need ' ') and lose the space between 5 and else.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 24 bytes

```
" "/{.,4>{-1%}{}if}%" "*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0lBSb9aT8fErlrXULW2ujYzrVYVKKb1/79HaqVCWmpOTn65QnJ@SqpCOlBXalExAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>152</s> <s>125</s> 106 bytes

- Saved 19 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
j;f(char*S){for(char*Z;*S;S=Z+!!*Z)for(Z=S+strcspn(S," "),j=0;Z-S>4&&--j*2>S-Z;Z[j]^=S[~j]^=Z[j]^=S[~j]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Na8MwDIbP269QDStx6sAYu3kJ5OOwXXqod3LWQcjsfJDGxTaUUbq/nsVtF7YdAkKy9D7Cr8qgKsthaKn0yrrQPsNHqfTlzanPKAv5arHwOXZjHrKVsbo0@95jBAHCpA3vKQ9Y9LhcBkHrP0Qs4JTn7fY9ZPmXK78aTE/Drmh6Dx9vb9wfEOfbED2LT5Ci69QBSvUhoFKdFNogeoUSB71AvIMC7KZo1pOSOuW1bgyMUfTK1kKDFcZORPaHmDTpxXi8OXEpdSnD43Svm95KDwHAnXnrn6JzQSQmZ48H1XVCXjwaLWSnKjS3lpAf1@um2NhZNiWTSy1qq/qr17mdjPy/bKRPwzc)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>132</s> 119 bytes

```
 s =input
s s arb . x (' ' | rpos(0)) rem . s
 x =gt(size(x),5) reverse(x)
 o =o x differ(s) ' ' :s(s)
 output =o x
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xDsIwDET3fMVtTSSEGGBBys5vUOpUkUJcxSktiH8PDtv53vlOMo@czq1B4GNe1mpE5b2MOGKHHTDgi7Kw2JNzKPRUX4wiP1cr8UN2d4dLJy8q0i8DhmdNTDEEKlYcestVVClbq478A4by1NqN3giUEm948ESYOemX/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
s/\S{5,}/reverse$&/eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RckxCoAwEAXR3lNsIVZKqtzBXksb0a8GQjZkgyLi1V3thKnmRSRvVcUM3WXr2yTsSIKyMlhVW5y0wHs@aOIZtLJfPi76zQl9jZQhmaZR8L/AeUP65eGYHQfRJr4)

Replace (`s///`) all (`/g`) at least 5 (`{5,}`) non-whitespace (`\S`) by the evaluation (`/e`) of `reverse$&`/the reversed match.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>67</s> 65  bytes

```
lambda s:' '.join([c[::-1]if len(c)>4 else c for c in s.split()])
```

Comment: `f=` is not needed unless it is recursive.  Saves 2.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <del>69</del> 66 bytes

```
s=>s.split` `.map(i=>i.length>4?[...i].reverse().join``:i).join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcYxDoAgDADArzDiYCcnE/AhxqREGy1BIJTw/bp408UwgpyNa59zuUhVnBeQmrijQXhDtew8Q6J898cv2w4AfECjQU3IThALZ8SV/xlU/QA)

Comment: You can replace `i.split''` with `[...i]`

Comment: `w[4]` is shorter than `w.length>4`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>73</s> 50 bytes

*-23 bytes thanks to Shaggy and ETHproductions*

```js
s=>s.replace(/\w{5,}/g,x=>[...x].reverse().join``)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/\w{5,}/g,x=>[...x].reverse().join``)

console.log(f("Hey fellow code golfers"))
console.log(f("I aM noT a cAr"))
console.log(f("I Am a tRaiN"))
```

Comment: You don't need to `split` on the spaces.

Comment: I think Shaggy means that the `.split` and `.join` are superfluous and can be removed, since `/\w{5,}/` doesn't match spaces. (You will have to add the `g` flag though)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 98 bytes

```
f: func[a][parse a[any[copy n[to{ }| to end](if(length? n)> 4[n: reverse n]prin n)skip(prin{ })]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc2xDgIhEIThV5lcdddbXaGtte2GgsByEsku4VBD1GdHrpv8yZcp7PuNPcj0sCI8xZE1lG3ZGZasNHKaG4SqfvD7oipYvJljmBPLVu8XyHLGiWRF4RcfTkwuUUbfHzHPxx50MWZcYLpyQ@CU9A2nnrFpCkNN/Q8)

### Ungolfed

```
f: func [a] [                         
    parse a [                            ; parse the argument on
        any [                            ; zero or more
            copy n [                     ; copy the matched substring to n 
                to { }                   ; scan to a space 
                | to end                 ; or to the end  
            ] 
            ( if (length? n) > 4 [       ; if the length of the match is bigger than 4 
                  n: reverse n           ; reverse the match  
              ]
            prin n)                      ; print the match   
            skip (prin { })              ; skip the space
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 53 bytes

An alternative, but slightly longer, method to the straightforward reversing of words of length ≥5, which Oliver beat me to.

```
s=>s.replace(/\S+/g,m=>[...m].sort(_=>!!m[4]).join``)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcyxDsIgEADQX6GdIOp1cYXZ3bE2LcGDtDm4hms0/Xr0fcDb/MdLqOt@3Aq/sUXbxDqBijv5gHp4PS9DumbrRgDIEwjXQ8/WdV0e75OBjdeyLKYFLsKEQJx01P0DTxWRiL8q/F@VmCJW6Y1pPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
for i in input().split():print i[::(-1,1)[len(i)<5]],
```

As far as I can see the , at the end does not leave a trailing space but please correct me if I am wrong.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVRCoAgDADQqwy/FCoo6Ec6QHcQv2rWYDgxIzr9Ch688rZT8qSapAIB5V@5m3XDVZj@famUG1Dw3vZjN7rAmC25ZY6xUzUrvpCQWR7YZEc4hBPWy3w)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 20 bytes

```
VcwdI>lN4p+_Nd.?p+Nd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyy5PMXTLsfPpEA73i9Fz75A2y/l/3@P1EqFtNScnPxyheT8lFSF9PyctNSiYj0FT4VEX4W8/BCFRIVkxyIdIN8xF8guCUrM9AMA)

```
Vcwd          | for N in input().split(" "):
    I>lN4     |     if len(N)>4:
        p+_Nd |         print(N[::-1]+" ", end="")
    .?        |     else:
        p+Nd  |         print(N+" ", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 131 bytes

```java
s->s.join(" ",java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).map(x->x.length()<5?x:new StringBuffer(x).reverse()+"").toArray(String[]::new))
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY@xTsMwEED3fsUpky2IN5YWisoEQzMAG2I4nEtxcOzIvrSpUL49OGAxIiSfdD6/871r8Yil78m19cesLcYIezTucwVgHFNoUBNUyxXgiYNxB9AiJ1FuUn1KkU5kZKOhAgc3cyy3UbXeOFFAcdmmGWpgY9UuBDxHFTkQdiIlvTW8MFKqDnsxlttRWXIHfhfy@up2XDs65bl3Q9NQEKNUgY4UIgl5URRSsf/@NUu9vK6XHinnzY9XP7zZ5JX1jt7U0KUFf3GUeblzZOqUH1j16YWtE05pUdzTGRqy1p9A@5rg4G3SiMl482ffA@AenH8GBL0L/8B3XUL5EU2V4Wk1zV8)

```java
s->                            // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.join(" ",                  //  Join String-array with spaces:
      java.util.Arrays.stream( //   An Array-stream of:
        s.split(" "))          //    The input-String split by spaces
      .map(w->                 //     Mapped to:
           w.length()<5?       //      If the word is not of length 5:
            w                  //       Leave the word as is
           :                   //      Else:
            new StringBuffer(x).reverse()+"")
                               //       Reverse it
      .toArray(String[]::new)) //   And convert the Stream to a String-array for the join
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸®zZÊ¨5©2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uK56WsqoNaky&input=IkhleSBmZWxsb3cgY29kZSBnb2xmZXJzIg)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 18 bytes

Port of my GolfScript answer.

```
lS/{_,4>{-1%}&}%S*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PydYvzpex8SuWtdQtVatVjVY6/9/j9RKhbTUnJz8coXk/JRUhfT8nLTUomIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
wm?↔Io>5Lw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzzX/lHbFM98O1Of8v///3ukViqkpebk5JcrJOenpCqk5@ekpRYVAwA)